# Обработка нажатия на GridView

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня gridView заполняется разметкой, содержащей textView и ImageButton. Мне нужно обрабатывать нажатие на ImageButton. Как и где сделать обработчик?

В зависимости от нажатой ImageButton на экране появляется соответствующий текст в DialogFragment. Что вызывает у меня дополнительный вопрос:

Я присваиваю кнопкам картинки из массива, можно ли по нажатию на кнопку, идентифицировать индекс присвоенной картинки из массива? Если да- то как это сделать, а если нет- как можно сопоставить нажатый ImageButton и текст в DialogFragment?

Comment: Обработчик лучше делать в адаптере. И использовать `RecyclerView`, а не `GridView`. А в диалог передавать номер позиции

Answer (score 0):

Можете почитать про библиотеку ButterKnife для отлова нажатия на кнопку. Пример использования этой библиотеки для события нажатия на View

```
@OnClick(R.id.signUp)
public void signUpClick(View view) {
    //Some code
}
```

Либо же в .xml файле у ImageButton указать

```
 android:onClick="someFunction"
```

А в коде

```
public void someFunction(View view) {
    //some code
}
```

По поводу второго, мне кажется, вы можете вызывать DialogFragment и заполнять его необходимым текстом прямо в методе, срабатывающим на нажатие на кнопку. Соответственно каждая кнопка будет вызывать соответствующий её текст